# How to denormalize this SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server, denormalized

I have a very wide table denormalized (if you can say that) like this, the option columns go to 100+

```
Year  ProductID ProductName Option1 Option2 Option3 ....Option100
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2016    1        Test1        A1      A1a     A3
2015    1        Test1        A1      A2      A2a
```

The problem is we have dynamic queries trying to determine the option column and then finding the option value in them

i.e.

```
@SQL= 'SELECT Option' + @getOptionNum +' FROM ProductMapping
```

Ideally I want this converted to something like this

```
Year ProductID ProductName OptionName
-------------------------------------
2016   1         Test1      Option1
2016   1         Test1      Option2
2016   1         Test1      Option3
2015   1         Test1      Option1
2015   1         Test1      Option2
2015   1         Test1      Option3

OptionID OptionName OptionValue  Year
-------------------------------------
  1        Option1     A1        2016
  2        Option2     A1a       2016
  3        Option3     A3        2016
  4        Option1     A1        2015
  5        Option2     A2        2015
  6        Option3     A2a       2015

SELECT * 
FROM ProductMapping map
LEFT JOIN OptionList list ON map.OptionName = list.OptionName
                          AND map.Year = list.Year
                          AND map.OptionName = 'Option1'
```

The problem I am running into is how to convert that wide table into the two tables structure through queries since it's a lot of columns and rows and I cannot normalize all of that manually.

Yes I also understand ideally the 2nd table needs to be normalized further to keep the Option1...Option3 in a separate table and the Option1..A1 mapping in a separate table but it's a start...

Hopefully the simple example sheds light of the following facts

1. Option1...100 columns need to be normalized in a separate table
2. The option columns to values mapping changes every year

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you considered using a document-store database as opposed to a relational (table) database? Extensible columns are a weakness of traditional RDBMS.

Comment: too many existing processes depend on these core tables...I am trying my alternative as a proof of concept to get rid of all of the dynamic queries we have going on

Comment: Why do you want a two table solution?   What does this get you that you can't get with a normalized single table?   Just add `OptionValue` to your first table and you have everything in one table, normalized.

Comment: Immediately stop...and fire the dba who designed this!

Comment: Why wouldn't you put the values in a single table?

Comment: Tab/Gordon: You are correct, at a second glance, I could potentially just put this in one table

Comment: I wish I could fire the dba but this thing has been in production for 10+ yrs and I just joined this firm and among other things, trying to help them clean up structure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (Year int,ProductID int,ProductName varchar(50),Option1 varchar(50),Option2 varchar(50),Option3 varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable values
(2016,1,'Test1','A1','A1a','A3'),
(2015,1,'Test1','A1','A2','A2a')

Declare @XML xml
Set @XML = (Select * from @YourTable for XML RAW)

Select * 
 From  (
        Select Year        = r.value('@Year','int')
              ,ProductID   = r.value('@ProductID','int')
              ,ProductName = r.value('@ProductName','varchar(50)')
              ,OptionName  = Attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
            From  @XML.nodes('/row') as A(r)
            Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*[local-name(.)!="ProductID"]') as B(Attr)
       ) A
 Where OptionName Like 'Option%'
 Order by Year Desc,OptionName

Select OptionID=Row_Number() over (Order By Year Desc,OptionName),* 
 From (
        Select OptionName  = Attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
              ,OptionValue = Attr.value('.','varchar(100)') 
              ,Year        = r.value('@Year','int')
         From  @XML.nodes('/row') as A(r)
         Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*[local-name(.)!="ProductID"]') as B(Attr)
         --CROSS APPLY A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(Attr)
        ) A 
 Where OptionName Like 'Option%'
```

Returns

```
Year    ProductID   ProductName OptionName
2016    1           Test1       Option1
2016    1           Test1       Option2
2016    1           Test1       Option3
2015    1           Test1       Option1
2015    1           Test1       Option2
2015    1           Test1       Option3
```

and

```
OptionID    OptionName  OptionValue Year
1           Option1     A1          2016
2           Option2     A1a         2016
3           Option3     A3          2016
4           Option1     A1          2015
5           Option2     A2          2015
6           Option3     A2a         2015
```

> **EDIT**

Now if you wanted a STRAIGHT Normalization

```
Declare @YourTable table (Year int,ProductID int,ProductName varchar(50),Option1 varchar(50),Option2 varchar(50),Option3 varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable values
(2016,1,'Test1','A1','A1a','A3'),
(2015,1,'Test1','A1','A2','A2a')

Declare @XML xml
Set @XML = (Select * from @YourTable for XML RAW)


Select ID    = r.value('@id','int')                             --<<'@id' Should be YOUR PK
      ,Item  = Attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
      ,Value = Attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
 From  @XML.nodes('/row') as A(r)
 Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*[local-name(.)!="id"]') as B(Attr)  --<<'id' Should be YOUR PK
 --CROSS APPLY A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(Attr)
```

Returns (the nulls would normally be your PK)

```
ID      Item        Value
NULL    Year        2016
NULL    ProductID   1
NULL    ProductName Test1
NULL    Option1     A1
NULL    Option2     A1a
NULL    Option3     A3
NULL    Year        2015
NULL    ProductID   1
NULL    ProductName Test1
NULL    Option1     A1
NULL    Option2     A2
NULL    Option3     A2a
```

Comment: this is absolutely brilliant! Works...however some OptionX columns have NULL, the Year shows up as NULL for them?

Comment: @SQLSeeker Let me take another stab at it

Comment: @SQLSeeker Just added dummy row for 2017 with a null in Option3.  I see two rows (in each set) for 2012.  Perhaps you could provide the sample

Comment: @SQLSeeker I have to ask, do you have nulls in the year?

Comment: hmm..could be..i am checking

Comment: what if I took your first query with the first select statement and wanted to see something like 2016  Test1 Option1 A1, 2016  Test1 Option1 A2..basically collapse the 2nd table back with the first one and create redundant rows?

Comment: @SQLSeeker Give me a couple of minutes

Comment: @SQLSeeker In your actual data, do you have a PK for each record?

Comment: you were right. Some entries had NULL in Year causing that set to all have YEAR with NULL

Comment: Selecting the entire table into an XML structure seems expensive - does this approach scale-well for millions of rows and hundreds of simultaneous queries?

Comment: @Dai Clearly we all know the answer would be a big fat NO.  But, just for fun, I took 100,000 records.  1) Select into XML 1.4 seconds 2) Actual Parsing of XML 0.2 seconds  3) Writing 593,866 records 9.65 seconds.  All in total was 11.25 seconds  (These were the worst, the fastest time was 9.587 seconds).    That said, its a utility which is primarily used on smaller record sets to feed my token'izer and/or web apps.  The real joy is that I don't have to code numerous field names, I only care about the PK.  Respectfully, John

Answer (score 1):

I would normalize the table into a single table with rows per option:

```
select pm.year, pm.productid, pm.productname, v.option, v.optionvalue
from productmapping pm cross apply
     (values ('option1', option1), ('option2', option2), . . .
     ) v(option, optionvalue);
```

I'm struggling with putting this into two tables, however.  I could imagine giving ids to the options (but not the option/value pairs).